# Is reflection of EM-waves just a "re-transmission"?

Tags: reflection

An electromagnetic wave impinging on the surface of metal will cause the free charges on the surface to accelerate which leads to radiation. Is this the basic idea of reflection? As certain surfaces like dry sand or the pavement in a city have poor conductivity, they are poor reflectors. As far as I understood, in those materials the wave will be absorbed and turned to heat energy which is the reason why pavement gets really hot on sunny days.

Comment: I think you've got it about right.

Answer (score 0):

You are right except there are also phenomena where electrons at low, normally stable orbits are kicked out to normally unmanned orbits by radiation. When those electrons return, you get new radiation. It can have different wavelength and it can be released delayed. But we do not call it reflection.

Insulators with high permittivity can reflect quite well because they have plenty of easily modifiable electron orbits in their material structure. The orbits only stretch and bend but do not get broken, so the material is insulator until the applied field is strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about retransmission, but in insulators this retransmission occurs via polarization of atoms, and, what is important, the part of the incident radiation that is not reflected is mostly refracted (passes inside the insulator). What happens after that depends on the material composition and geometry, for example, part of the refracted radiation can be reflected by underlying layers.